# Regex to test for int pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Fairly simple I assume. I need to build a regex pattern to match and pull out the pattern int,int,int form a string. I would like it to include negative ints too though (I then want to sub into this string a computed value);

e.g.

```
1,2,3
-1,3,5
100,-2,-3
```

etc

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d,\d,\d");
```

However, I dont think his takes into account negatives?

an example string maybe

> value={2,3,4},value2=test,value3={-13,0,0},anothervalue=234,nextvalue={0,0,2}

Comment: How many numbers can be in the comma-separated list?

Comment: as above I only need to match for the {\d,\d,\d} so ideally I would like to pull out all matches of this pattern from the string to a string array?

Comment: do you want to match from whole string OR individual values e.g. value, value2 etc.

Comment: What if the value in the string won't fit into an `int`? like "1111111111111111111111111111111111,2,3" ?

Comment: it would be the whole string. i.e. i'm happy to pull out the {d,d,d} an array and then parse this

Comment: If the input ends up being out of range, then he will have another problem, and therefore another SO question.  For this question, the answers below solved his problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the information you have provided

To include negative numbers, Change your regex as below:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\-?\d,\-?\d,\-?\d");
```

To include more than `one unit` digits

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\-?\d+,\-?\d+,\-?\d+");
```

Comment: This will match only signle digits

Comment: @w.b Perhaps you are correct, but I believe escaping a character will not have an effect so the regex should still be correct.

Comment: This pattern matches numbers outside `int` range, like 9999999999

Comment: Note that the OP asked for int *pattern*. He may want to just do the final validation using `int.TryParse` or similar.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you are correct at the moment I just want to pull out the values to an array. I will then use a try parse when I split

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option in addition to Waqar's pattern.

```
-?\d[0-9]*,-?\d[0-9]*,-?\d[0-9]*
```

Comment: This fails for the simple test cases `1,2,3` and `-1,-2,-3`.

Comment: Sorry i guess i could have posted with code format instead of quote. Updated regex.

Answer (score 0):

\d only matches a single numeric character

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"-?\d+,-?\d+,-?\d+");
```